# Insert statement with multiple rows include same selection field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to make multiple insert but all this new records will have same field which is retrieved from one of other table:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `retrieved`) VALUES
(null, "A", "A", SELECT id from user_records where id = 1),
(null, "B", "B", SELECT id from user_records where id = 1),
(null, "C", "C", SELECT id from user_records where id = 1)...
```

how can i insert this select result without executing for every record?

thank you

Comment: I think variable will help

Comment: I don't understand the use of select statement, as you are selecting id field and in where condition too you have filtered rows by id field. I think I am missing your intent here, please clarify.

Comment: @DipenduPaul probably he oversimplified the original query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use variable for that:

```
SET @VAR := SELECT id 
              FROM user_records 
             WHERE id = 1;

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `retrieved`) 
VALUES
(null, "A", "A", @VAR),
(null, "B", "B", @VAR),
(null, "C", "C", @VAR)...
```

or

```
SELECT id INTO @VAR 
  FROM user_records 
 WHERE id = 1;

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `retrieved`) 
VALUES
(null, "A", "A", @VAR),
(null, "B", "B", @VAR),
(null, "C", "C", @VAR)...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you declare and assign a var

```
DECLARE user_id INT;
SET user_id = (SELECT id from user_records where id = 1);
```

Then, use the var in the insert query

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `retrieved`) VALUES
(null, "A", "A", user_id),
(null, "B", "B", user_id),
(null, "C", "C", user_id)
```

Comment: Are you sure you can do this in MySQL ?

Comment: this work for me, also @Alexander post a similar answer